# Select the value of max(date) and id with mysql

Tags: mysql, query

I want the last dated record. But my query doesn't work. Where am I doing wrong?

Example data:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id |    messagges   |       mes_date      |  send_user | rec_user |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | hello          | 2019-01-18 12:12:12 |      7     |     1    |
| 2  | forget         | 2019-01-16 10:10:10 |      8     |     3    |
| 3  | say            | 2019-02-20 14:14:14 |      9     |     1    |
| 4  | drink          | 2018-12-16 08:08:08 |      10    |     3    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My query:

```
SELECT distinct lst.id,lst.messagges,lst.mes_date, lst.rec_user
FROM mes_table lst
join (select mes_date, id from messagges 
order by mes_date desc) as msg on lst.id = msg.id
group by lst.rec_user
```

I need:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| id |    messagges   |       mes_date      |   rec_user |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | forget         | 2019-01-16 10:10:10 |      3     |
| 3  | say            | 2019-02-20 14:14:14 |      1     |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  The do roughly the same thing.
- When you want *just* the last, use `ORDER BY .. DESC LIMIT 1`

Simplify to

```
SELECT   lst.id, lst.messagges, lst.mes_date, lst.rec_user
    FROM  mes_table AS lst
    JOIN  messagges AS msg ON msg.id = lst.id
    ORDER BY  msg.mes_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
```